# How can I move my borderlands 2 save files

Tags: borderlands-2

I'm moving stuff between two PCs and I have a save file on one for a borderlands 2 game that I've been playing. I want to put that onto the borderlands 2 game on the second PC. Problem is, that whenever I replace the save files in the second PC with my save and then start up the game, the only available option is to start a new game. It overwrites the save files I give it and makes a new blank one. 
Any ideas?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on a non-steam version of the game? Otherwise you can just use the steam cloud saves to sync your data.

Comment: save files can be copied around, I've backed up/save edited locally, but yeah steam cloud should work. There arent' non-steam versions best I'm aware, since it uses Steamworks for multiplayer

Comment: Yeah it's a non steam version, I'm just toying around to see how well it runs. It should be a simple matter of copying over the save file I want to use, but the game doesn't seem to want to use it.

Comment: I had that issue with Borderlands 1; I got around it by Alt-tabbing out of the game once I was at the "Press Any Key" screen and copying the save files into the folder at that point. Unfortunately, BL2 searches for DLC *after* that step, so I'm not sure it'll work. Might be worth a shot though.

Comment: "non-Steam" version of a Steamworks game, means pirated, I guess?

Comment: @TZHX Some games do have legitimate non-Steam versions but as far as I can tell, Borderlands 2 is not one of them.

Comment: @Studoku Yes... I know that some games do. But Borderlands 2 doesn't. It is a Steamworks game. Retail copies provide a CD key that activates on Steam. I wasn't suggesting that Steam is the only way to get any games on PC.

Answer (score 2):

### Use Steam Cloud

Steam Cloud has arguably been designed for exactly this purpose. If you don't want steam to sync your saves all the time, you can turn it on for just a few minutes until Steam has synced with first the old PC and the new PC afterwards. You can also clear the Steam Cloud afterwards.

Note: There is no reason not to use Steam Cloud, since you possess a **legal copy of the game**. I know that you do because otherwise [you couldn't be asking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) this question here.

Comment: Ooh, snarky. I like this answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I've figured it out! When you open up the game (going to the main menu), Borderlands will automatically create a save folder if none is found. It will be a random number folder. Copy all the save info from the save folder you want to use, into the one the computer created then restart the game. Voila! It worked for me so I'm happy :D

Answer (score 0):

Ok, You go into documents, go into my games, go into borderlands, willow-game, save-data, random numbers, then there are all you save files, copy them all onto a USB. Then go into the random number folder, then copy the save files.

Comment: I've done all that already. Problem is that the save files that I copy aren't used when I put them in the folder on the second computer. Instead, the game overwrites them with a blank save

Comment: have you copied both files of the save